# How to install fabric-sdk-py in my Easpberry Pi4

Tags: hyperledger, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to install fabric-sdk-py on Raspberry Pi 4 but It does not install. I want to send some sensor data from my raspberry pi 4 to my Hyperledger fabric network, I have a python script to read data from MQ4 and DHT11 sensors. I was trying to use the fabric python sdk